# Calculating average value per month and returning a single average

Tags: sql, jdbc

I am calculating average per month that should return a single average so i did an average of average , It has to be a one to many relationship between trucks table and orders , and i am using row mapper for spring jdbc

```
Select truckId,  truckCode,  purchasedDate, 
descriptions, orderId, petrolQty, orderDate, avg(avgPetrolQty) as avgPerMonth, truckId from (
SELECT  t.truckId, t.truckCode, t.purchasedDate, t.descriptions, o.orderId, o.petrolQty, o.orderDate,
COALESCE(monthname(o.orderDate),'Not Announced') as month,
IFNULL (avg(o.petrolQty),0) as avgPetrolQty  
from truck t left join orderz o 
on t.truckId = o.truckId 
where t.truckId = 3
group by  t.truckCode, o.orderId, o.orderDate
) group by truckCode, orderId
```

so i have such orders that belong to truckId 3 
here is the full result

```
TRUCKID     TRUCKCODE   PURCHASEDDATE   DESCRIPTION     ORDERID     PETROLQTY   ORDERDATE   AVGPERMONTH     TRUCKID  
3   BY2354  2005-05-01  BLACK TOYOTA 15 1   13.0    2006-01-21  13.0    3
3   BY2354  2005-05-01  BLACK TOYOTA 15 2   53.0    2002-01-21  53.0    3
```

Which gives two avgPermonth How can i write a better sql
and my sql above gives average per month as 100

which is not right even when i add more orders it doesnt change untill after 4 or more new orders then it gives some non logical average, What am i doing wrong , and its important my sql gets full detail of both tables orderId can be ommitted if it affects solution

Comment: How do we know it is not right?  What is wrong with the calculation?  Your code and sample results make no sense.  Just count the number of columns.

Comment: this is just part of the result set i can post all of it